# All application disappeared in windows 8 start menu

Tags: windows-8, start-menu

I had problems launching windows 8, every time I start the PC, it hands in the start menu, and I can't do anything (Open desktop or any other application), so I booted in linux, and i cleared the windows 8 registry Run`directory, and i cleared the`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`, well it helped, and i can now open windows, but all the application and tiles in windows start menu, are disappeared, i can't even do a search in the start menu, and i couldn't do a restore cause i had no restore point :(.

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Just put new shortcuts in that folder.  I suggest using doing a Refresh since you didn't backup the shortcuts before you deleted them.

Comment: well i copied the files from `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\`to the start menu folder, it recovered "SOME" of the apps, but other apps like the "Desktop" tile, didnt show up :(

Comment: Yes; Your solution is to Refresh your installation. You shouldn't have just blindly deleted files.  Desktop tile isn't require `Win+D` gets you to the desktop

Comment: Yes, that's what i've used, anyways, i fixed it using `sfc /scannow`

Comment: `sfc /scannow` is't the Windows 8 only Refresh feature

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this problem by running `sfc /scannow`